# Who's to blame for copyright content, webmaster or site/business owner?

Tags: copyright

If I upload content that is clearly a violation of copyrights am I legally responsible for such content or is it only the owner of the site and business?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can **both** be sued, civilly and criminally, depending on the nature of the content and the jurisdiction the act takes place in. At minimum the site will receive a take-down or cease and desist request.

> ***I'm not a lawyer in any jurisdiction, this isn't legal advice, it's opinion.***

Comment: It would also depend on how sound the website's User Agreement or Terms of Use is. In your scenario, if the site has an air-tight Terms of Use agreement putting the legal burden on you, then you're the only one that can be sued (Theoretically). `I'm not a lawyer either, it is only my opinion.`

Comment: Interesting answers, thank you. I think I should have my clients sign a letter saying they will take full responsibility of any law suits or penalties brought on pertaining to illegal, misuse or infringements of copyright content and that I'm in no way held accountable for what I upload. Some sort of legal jargon that frees me to do my job and still hold them accountable in case something happens.

Comment: @EKet such things still don't protect google from these law suits!